# JSPDF-Autotable colspan/rowpan issue

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have an html table with rowspan/colspan.I am using jspdf and jspdf-autotable for exporting that html table to pdf. However the pdf getting saved has a table which doesn't contain rowspan/colspan in actual table.How to do colspan/rowspan using jspdf-autotable?
My current code is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/someatoms/jsPDF-AutoTable/master/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{

 var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("my-table"));
    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {startY: 40});
    doc.save("Report.pdf");
}

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <table border='1' id="my-table">
<thead>
<tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan='2'>D</td>
<td colspan='2'>$100</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td >E</td>
<td >F</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Version 3 of the library supports rowspans and colspans, no hacks needed

The plugin doesn't support to automatically port colspans and rowspans from html. However you can do it manually. Check out this [example](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js#L258) (a demo is [here](https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/#spans)).

Comment: Posting code is better than links which might not show the solution anymore

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime the plugin seems to support parsing the colspans from HTML. This should work:

```html
<td colspan="2">Colspan</td>
```