# jsPDF - Header table with rowspan and colspan attributes

Tags: javascript, jspdf-autotable

Based in this [example](http://codepen.io/wefs/pen/qaRBEp) I need to export the respective table but for some reason the pdf file generated doesn't recognize the rowspan and colspan attributes and the generated table looks different.

HTML view

```
<table id="table" border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">ID</th>
    <th colspan="2">Names</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Email</th>
    <th colspan="2">Addresses</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>IP-address1</th>
    <th>IP-address2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">1</td>
    <td>Donna</td>
    <td>Moore</td>
    <td>dmoore0@furl.net</td>
    <td>211.56.242.221</td>
    <td>211.56.242.221</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">2</td>
    <td>Janice </td>
    <td>Henry</td>
    <td>jhenry1@theatlantic.com</td>
    <td>38.36.7.199</td>
    <td>38.36.7.199</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">3</td>
    <td>Ruth</td>
    <td>Wells</td>
    <td>rwells2@constantcontact.com</td>
    <td>19.162.133.184</td>
    <td>19.162.133.184</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">4</td>
    <td>Jason</td>
    <td>Ray</td>
    <td>jray3@psu.edu</td>
    <td>10.68.11.42</td>
    <td>10.68.11.42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">5</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Stephens</td>
    <td>jstephens4@go.com</td>
    <td>47.32.129.71</td>
    <td>47.32.129.71</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">6</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Nichols</td>
    <td>anichols5@com.com</td>
    <td>18.186.38.37</td>
    <td>18.186.38.37</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">6</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Nichols</td>
    <td>anichols5@com.com</td>
    <td>18.186.38.37</td>
    <td>18.186.38.37</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">6</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Nichols</td>
    <td>anichols5@com.com</td>
    <td>18.186.38.37</td>
    <td>18.186.38.37</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Script

```
function createPDF(){
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    var IDtable = document.getElementById('table');
    var tableSource = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(IDtable);
    doc.autoTable(tableSource.columns, tableSource.data, {startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 40, theme: 'grid'});
    doc.save("file.pdf")
}
```

Comment: @SimonBengtsson Can you give me a hand with this little inconvenience? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSPDF-Autotable colspan/rowpan issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510636/jspdf-autotable-colspan-rowpan-issue)

Comment: @SimonBengtsson Thanks for response. I have been trying to apply the spans() function based in the example.js library but I don't know how to use it because in the demo page the colspan and rowspan attributes are being used in the body table but I need it to use them in the head table. Please, any idea in order to get the same result as my html example?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version rowspans and colspans are automatically handled so this should be enough.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.autoTable({html: '#table'});
doc.save("file.pdf")
```